# Page doesn't recoginze the export on a React Module when there's actually an export

Tags: html, reactjs, import, export, yarnpkg

right now I'm practicing with the Three.js library, but I've been having some trouble with the exports...
Here is the `App.jsx:`

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import React from "react"

import { Contact } from "../components/Contact"
import { Hero } from "../components/Hero"
import { Works } from "../components/Works"
import { Who } from "../components/Who"

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
 
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  color: white;
  background: url("./img/bg.jpeg");
  &::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
  };
  
`

function App() {

  return (
    <Container>
      <Hero/>
      <Who/>
      <Works/>
      <Contact/>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App
```

and here is the `Works.jsx` component itself

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Section = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
`;


export default  Works = () => {
  return (
    <Section> </Section>
  );
};
```

The error that is shown in the navigator console is this one:

[The requested module does not provide an export named 'Works'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvYlY.png)

[Navigator source console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySIfC.png)

Also i've noticed this when i pass the mouse over the import in the App.jsx:

[Works import - doesn't Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQiZ8.png) This is the `Works.jsx` import

[Contacts import - it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyIdw.png) and this is the message from the `Contacts.jsx` import

I really don't know where this error is coming from, i've tried everything and nothing seems to work, im using React, Vite, yarn and styled-components

When I delete  Works.js component from the import everything seems to work just fine.
[working good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fo55.png)

Comment: Try `export const Works = () => ()` instead of `export default Works`, and check if it works.

Comment: `import Works from "../components/Works"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change:**

```
export default Works = () => { return... }
```

**To:**

```
const Works = () => { return... }
export { Works }
```

**Or:**

```
export const Works = () => { return... }
```

You are importing 'Works' on App.jsx as named exports, but you are exporting it as a default export. Either change the import to `import Works from "../components/works"` or follow the instructions above.

I hope I've helped!

Comment: tysm! i haven't touched React for some time and I didn't remember the {} affect the imports